# Which static resources are used for the Windows Phone keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, staticresource

Does anyone knows which (if any) StaticResources are used for the Windows Phone keyboard?

I'm creating my own keyboard (with only numbers, a clear all and a enter/search button) and want it to look like the default keyboard (fontsize, background and border color etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom control and shape it the way you need. You don't have access to any of the keyboard styles.

Check this guy out, he creates a keyboard from scratch:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have seen the link. But I want the same look and feeling as in the buildin keyboards. I have created my own "keyboard buttons", but need info of which StaticRessources I can use to get the same font size, color etc.

Comment: Trial an error my friend ;) Windows Phone has a PhoneFontSize static resource, you can try to see which one fits, otherwise just use numbers. Same goes for color and etc...

Comment: Well... I had hoped that I could use some default resource to style the keys... To avoid "guessing" som values that could change in the next version or is different in each resolution.